# Elasticsearch - creating alias with is_write parameter in index template file

Tags: elasticsearch, alias

I am creating an index template through java api and I did something like this (the code is below)

I though that in that way, the alias `rolledoverAliasObj` would have the parameter `is_write_index:true` but at the end, when I check the aliases that are created it looks like this:

```
"aliases" : {
  "all-alias" : { },
  "recent-alias" : { },
  "rolledover-alias" : { },
  "write-alias" : { }
},
```

any ideas why it is not putting the parameter `is_write_index` in the alias `rolledover-alias`?

```
    Alias rolledoverAliasObj = new Alias(rolledoverAlias).writeIndex(true);
    request.alias(new Alias(writeAlias))
            .alias(new Alias(allAlias))
            .alias(new Alias(recentAliasName))
            .alias(rolledoverAliasObj);
    request.settings(getIndexSettings());
    restHighLevelClient.indices().putTemplate(request, RequestOptions.DEFAULT);
```